# how can I calculate the steps in a discrete function of feComponentTransfer in linearRGB color space

Tags: svg-filters

I'm trying to make a discrete gradient using the feComponentTransfer functions like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" standalone="no"?>
<!DOCTYPE svg PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD SVG 1.1//EN" 
  "http://www.w3.org/Graphics/SVG/1.1/DTD/svg11.dtd">
<svg x="0" y="0" width="500px" height="120px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
   <title>A discrete gradient</title> 
   <defs>
    <linearGradient id="inputImage" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
       <stop offset="0" stop-color="black"/>
       <stop offset="1" stop-color="white"/>
    </linearGradient>
    <filter id="discrete" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" color-interpolation-filters="linearRGB">     
       <feComponentTransfer>
          <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues=".666667 .6      .533333 .466667 .4      .333333 .266667 .2      .133333 .066667"/>
          <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues=".666667 .6      .533333 .466667 .4      .333333 .266667 .2      .133333 .066667"/>
          <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues=".933333 .866667 .8      .733333 .666667 .6      .533333 .466667 .4      .333333"/>      
       </feComponentTransfer>       
    </filter>   
   </defs>
   <rect x="10px" y="10px" width="480px" height="100px" fill="url(#inputImage)" filter="url(#discrete)"/>
</svg>
```

1. I was expecting to see these colors: #AAAAEE, #9999DD, #8888CC, #7777BB, #6666AA, #555599, #444488, #333377, #222266, #111155 but, instead, Firefox* displayed these: #D5D5F7, #CBCBEF, #C1C1E7, #B6B6DE, #AAAAD5, #9C9CCB, #8D8DC1, #7C7CB6, #6666AA, #49499C respectively, which gave a similar blend but a few tones brighter. I know that this filter's job is to adjust the brightness, the contrast etc. however I don't understand how it works in this case. So, the question here is how should I calculate the steps in the tableValues - inside the linearRGB color space - in order to display exactly the colors I want.
2. I noticed that most of the component values of the displayed (output) colors are mapped completely out of the given ranges, and I was wondering -please correct me if I'm wrong- how is that agrees with the spec.
3. Since I don't understand how these functions work in linearRGB color space, I decided to get manually the colors I want. I tried random values and after thousands of attempts, I finally found the steps for the first 6 desired colors (#AAAAEE, #9999DD, #8888CC, #7777BB, #6666AA, #555599) and the ninth one (#222266). For the seventh desired color (#444488, R:68|0.266667, G:68|0.266667, B:136|0.533333) I found easily the feFuncB step but couldn't find a value for red and green functions to output exactly 68|0.266667. So the closest to the desired #444488 gave me the value 0.058823 for red and green, which outputs a near #454588 instead. I faced the same problem also with the desired 8th (#333377) and 10th (#111155) colors for which the closest outputs I could achieved was #353577 and #0D0D55 respectively.
   Here are the tableValues written in a way to output (almost) all the colors I wanted in the first place*:

> ```
>   <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues=".4    .317647 .247058 .184313 .133333 .09     .058823 .0353   .015686 .0039"/>
>   <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues=".4    .317647 .247058 .184313 .133333 .09     .058823 .0353   .015686 .0039"/>
>   <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues=".8588 .721568 .603921 .498039 .4      .317647 .247    .184313 .13333  .09"/>
> ```

Now I repeat the question: Is there an easy way (mathematical type, a multiplier or something) to use in order to have specified colors displayed, without wasting time testing random decimals?

- the results are from Firefox 60.0.2 on Ubuntu 16.4 64-bit Gnome, checked with the Gpick tool and, as you already know, differ from other rendering engines on the same or on other OS. At this time I'm only interested in how it works or, better, in how it should work.

Thanks in advance

Spyros Andredakis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before I answer, you need to be really careful of what your eyedropper is telling you are the color values. If you want to get a specific color in standard sRGB or linearRGB space, make sure that your eyedropper is set to that space.

That said if you're going to do a transform in linearRGB, but you want to get a specific color in sRGB as the result, then you need to specify the equivalent of the target sRGB color in linearRGB terms. You do this by using the gamma correction formula.

For example, if you want the first color in your gradient to be #AAAAEE in sRGB, then you have to do the following correction (in decimal) to your array inputs:

Color in linearRGB = ((Color in sRGB+0.055)/1.055)^2.4

So, for example, the first R/G/B values in your component transfer array should be

R : 0.402 = ((.6667 + 0.055)/1.055)^2.4

G : 0.402 = ((.6667 + 0.055)/1.055)^2.4

B : 0.855 = ((.9333 + 0.055)/1.055)^2.4

This formula is not accurate 100% in general - you need to use a different formula when the sRGB unit value is less than 0.04045 (L=S/12.92). But all your target values are above 0.04 so we don't need to worry.

Full result:

```html
    <svg x="0" y="0" width="500px" height="120px" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink">
       <title>A discrete gradient</title> 
       <defs>
        <linearGradient id="inputImage" gradientUnits="objectBoundingBox" x1="0%" y1="0%" x2="100%" y2="0%">
           <stop offset="0" stop-color="black"/>
           <stop offset="1" stop-color="white"/>
        </linearGradient>

        <filter id="discrete" filterUnits="objectBoundingBox" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%">        
       <feComponentTransfer>
          <feFuncR type="discrete" tableValues="0.4020 0.3185 0.2462 0.1845 0.1329 0.0908 0.0578 0.0331 0.0160 0.0056"/>
          <feFuncG type="discrete" tableValues="0.4020 0.3185 0.2462 0.1845 0.1329 0.0908 0.0578 0.0331 0.0160 0.0056"/>
          <feFuncB type="discrete" tableValues="0.8550 0.7231 0.6038 0.4969 0.4020 0.3185 0.2462 0.1845 0.1329 0.0908"/>        
       </feComponentTransfer>     
           </feComponentTransfer>      
        </filter>   
       </defs>
       <rect x="10px" y="10px" width="480px" height="100px" fill="url(#inputImage)" filter="url(#discrete)"/>
    </svg>
```

Comment: Ah. I re-read your question - I think I know what you want now & will edit.

Comment: That answered 100% my question. Now I know what I was looking for. I have some questions about this formula but don't bother. I'll read the theory. Thanks a lot